# Retrieve just one value for each id in column A in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a sheet in excel with the data in columns A, B and C set out like this. I have data in other columns as well, but I just need the values in A and B. The data in the columns look like this.

```
A        B           C
AM01771 GQ180944.1  93.75
AM01771 AY572862.2  100
AM07535 FJ668632.1  100
AM07535 KM245641.1  100
AM07535 KM245640.1  100
AM07535 KM245639.1  100
AM07535 HM152540.1  100
AM07535 EF206317.1  100
AM07535 EF206316.1  100
AM07535 EF206314.1  100
AM02943 JF683373.1  100
AM02943 KR144314.1  92.857
AM02943 KR143318.1  92.857
AM02943 JQ756315.1  92.857
AM02943 JQ756314.1  92.857
AM02943 EF206317.1  92.857
AM02943 EF206316.1  92.857
AM02943 EF206314.1  92.857
AM02943 AY140918.1  100
AM02943 AY572864.1  92.857
AM08919 GQ180944.1  92.857
AM08919 FJ792774.1  100
AM06386 JQ972694.1  100
AM06386 EF363230.1  100
AM06386 HQ003932.1  100
AM11267 KC751537.1  100
AM11267 FJ226408.1  100
AM11267 FJ226407.1  100
AM11267 FJ226406.1  100
AM11267 FJ226405.1  100
AM11267 FJ226404.1  100
AM11267 FJ226403.1  100
AM11267 FJ226402.1  100
AM11267 FJ226401.1  100
AM11267 FJ226400.1  100
AM11267 FJ226399.1  100
AM11267 FJ226398.1  100
AM11267 FJ226397.1  100
AM11267 FJ226396.1  100
AM11267 FJ226395.1  100
AM11267 FJ226394.1  100
AM11267 FJ226393.1  100
AM11267 FJ226392.1  100
AM11267 FJ226391.1  100
AM11267 FJ226390.1  100
AM11267 FJ226389.1  100
AM11267 FJ226388.1  100
AM11267 AY572859.2  100
AM11267 DQ279470.1  100
AM08207 EF206317.1  100
AM08207 EF206316.1  100
AM08207 EF206314.1  100
AM11432 KC569744.1  88.235
AM11432 FJ792773.1  100
AM11432 JX513905.1  100
AM11432 GQ180946.1  92.857
AM11432 AY572858.2  100
```

I want to get an output like this

```
   A         B
AM01771 GQ180944.1
AM07535 FJ668632.1
AM02943 JF683373.1
AM08919 GQ180944.1
AM06386 JQ972694.1
AM11267 KC751537.1
```

I am looking to retrieve just the first unique id for each value in column A from column B. Please suggest an easy method to do this. I have 4000 plus data points in each column.

Comment: @fixer1234 i went through the whole excel sheet and luckily, all the values in column C were above 70, hence that requirement didn't really matter. I did not want to edit the question again and bring it up on the site, hence accepted the answer and let it be. I can edit the question if needed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would like to suggest you a simple method by using *HELPER column*.

**Note: In your case no need to compare values from Column C because, all values are Greater than 70, so that the First Unique IDs from Column A & B will be Filtered only.**

*Check the Screen Shot below:*

[image]

In D2 write this Formula: `=COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2)` & fill it down. And Filter the entire data on Helper column for the values are 1.

**N.B.** I've used some of the rows from source data shown by you, you can include as many as you wish to. Also, *if you don't want Value 1 & Helper column in result area please delete them.*

Comment: "In your case no need to compare values from Column C because, all values are Greater than 70, so that the First Unique IDs from Column A & B will be Filtered only." - as OP wrote he need to consider only data above 70, the real data probably HAS VALUES BELOW 70, please don't judge real data based on example. Otherwise it's a great approach! Just needs a bit of improvement.

Comment: @MátéJuhász, OP wrote, **"first unique id for each value in column A from column B provided that the value in column c is greater than 70. If this value is less than 70, then pick the second id"**, how could I ignore it & the shown data !!

Comment: This is another case where you've written an answer that worked for the limited data shown in the OP's example but does not solve the problem as described in the question.  Your answer only appears to "work" because you have left out the cases where it doesn't.

Comment: In this case, the OP recognized that the data didn't contain the condition and modified the question so that your answer now applies.  So you lucked out in this one case with a wrong answer.  But this is an ongoing problem where you post an answer that doesn't address what is described in the question.  Please stop doing that because in a Q&A format it wastes readers time with answers that are wrong for the question asked.  If you think such answers have value, post a new question that it answers and do a self-answer.

Comment: "Ongoing problem" is an understatement.